# How to convert the date in a http header to an accepted input date for the linux command

Tags: linux, date, busybox

I am currently grabbing the date from an http header using this command:

```
wget --no-cache -S -O /dev/null google.com 2>&1 | sed -n -e 's/ *Date: *//p' -eT -eq
```

It's output is: `Thu, 26 Oct 2017 20:19:57 GMT`

I then need to convert this output to an accepted input that the BusyBox date command will accept, i.e.:

```
date --set="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"
```